# How to AWS trigger lambda on a specific time or date for n number of tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a scenario when i will have set of tasks to be executed at specific timing.
for example

```
task1: 28-06-2020 1:00 AM
task2: 30-06-2020 2:00 AM
task3: 01-07-2020 12:00 PM
.
.
.
n
```

i want to trigger my lambda(where me logic is defined), at these specified timing.
Probably i would be storing my timings to execute in a database,
can some tell me a way to execute lambda at a specified time.
I know we have TTL mechanism in dynamo which can trigger lambda but it delays the execution by 48 hours.I want my lambda to execute at the precise timings

Answer (score 6):

You can use CloudWatch Events [cron expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) for specific dates to **execute only once**. You would have to create rules for each date in question. This is based on the assumption that there is **no regular pattern** to repeatability of the dates.

The rules would trigger your lambda at these specific dates.

For example, for your dates in the question, you could use:

#### 28-06-2020

[image]

#### 30-06-2020

[image]

Comment: but there is a limitations to create rules which is 50 rules per account in cloudwatch . This would not be efficient . also if i had to execute at a specific time like 26-06-2020 1:15 PM. this would not work.

Comment: @joe123 Why it wouldn't work at 26-06-2020 1:15 PM? And how many dates to you need at once?

Comment: it will depend based on user requests, there can be n no. of task may be 50-1000 per day ..any other alternate solution do you have ?

Comment: @joe123 If DynamoDb TTL and CW Events are not suited, then you have to fully architect and implement your own solution for that.

Comment: i was unable to get any solutions thats the reason i posted on this forum,,. thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 4):

Given that you will have potentially 1000+ events at various times of day, you will need to implement your own solution. I would recommend:

- Store events in a **database** (eg date, time, repetition pattern)
- Use AWS CloudWatch Events to trigger an **AWS Lambda function every minute**
- Code the Lambda function to:

  - **Query** the database for unprocessed events that are due (or past-due)
  - Invoke the appropriate **Lambda function**
  - **Delete the event** from the database, or mark it as processed (for repeating events, store a 'last processed' time)

Functions will potentially be invoked a few seconds late due to these processing steps, but that should be fine unless you need high-precision timing.

Answer (score 3):

Steps Functions as an ad-hoc scheduler could be a good option for the use-case.

1. Query the database and Schedule execution for the specific date/time in Step Function state machine
2. In Step Function execution, map the lambda that needs to be triggered
3. Once the lambda is triggered at the desired time, the required business functionalities can be implemented.

**References:**

https://medium.com/serverless-transformation/serverless-event-scheduling-using-aws-step-functions-b4f24997c8e2

https://meetrix.io/blog/aws/06-using-step-functions-to-schedule-your-lambda.html

https://blog.smirnov.la/step-functions-as-an-ad-hoc-scheduling-mechanism-ed1787e44bb1

Comment: Thank you i think this solution works using the step function timestamp Path we can wait the execution till maximum of 1 year. We can input the timestamp as input to the step function dynamically